# Deserializing XML to POJO with dynamic tags

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo

I have a XML -

```
<member>
     <name>product_type</name>
     <value>Regular</value>
 </member>
 <member>
     <name>product_nid</name>
     <value>
       <i4>12345</i4>
     </value>
 </member>
```

So, I have created Arraylist as I have multiple Member fields in XML. But, problem is for some value tag there is  tag and for some there is actual value.

How can we handle this in same Java class?

Answer (score 0):

> How can we handle this in same Java class?

You're not supposed to. XML doesn't see this as `<value>` sometimes containing the text directly and sometimes having an element that contains the text.

XML sees this as `<value>` containing mixed content, that is to say text, that can optionally be annotated by elements `<i4>` that contain part of the text, such as:

```
<value>This is <i4>some</i4> fine <i4>text</i4>.</value>
```

The most useful way to cope with the situation is to not be in it, and instead use XML like you're supposed to, to express what is supposed to be expressed. So, decide once and for all whether `<value>` contains the text directly or contains an element that contains the text, and always follow that one decision.

You may have a need to express some further information about the value, telling whether it's an i4 or whatsnot. That would be a fine use of an attribute on the `value` element.

Comment: Actually, I am writing automation for XML based API's. As part of HTTP response I 'm getting above XML which I would like to parse using POJO. So, maybe I don't have control over what should be in <value>. Thanks!

Comment: That seems to indicate that this XML response is a poor choice for a POJO or at least for being automatically deserialized with JAXB. And should rather be analyzed with JDOM or StAX to extract the wanted information and put them in a POJO more specialized than what this XML format proposes.